# checkbox within multiselectbox here onChange is not working

Tags: javascript, html

I am using a multi selector in this Inside this select box i am using check box on Change of  this select I want to perform a function name getValue(). I tried this but for me its not working

Below is my code

```
 <html>
    <head>  
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ui.dropdownchecklist.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="demo.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="ui.core.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="ui.dropdownchecklist.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
               $("#cboLocation").dropdownchecklist({ firstItemChecksAll: true, maxDropHeight: 100 });
            });
            function getValue()
            {
                alert("hai");
                return false;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

          <select name="cboLocation" class="width150" id="cboLocation" multiple="multiple" onChange="getValue()">
            <option>(all)</option>
            <option>Banana Nut</option>
            <option>Black Walnut</option>
            <option>Burgundy Cherry</option>
            <option>Butter Pecan</option>
            <option>Strawberry Cheesecake</option>
            <option>Turkish Coffee</option>
            <option>Vanilla</option>
          </select>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I removed the onChange event from your select menu, as it is ignored by dropdownchecklist().Dropdownchecklist() is replacing your select element with `divs` and `inputs`; thus, the inline script isn't being called.

The following code does one thing: When a user finishes interacting with the dropdown menu, they are presented with the alert message 'hai', if and only if at least one checkbox is checked.

```
<select name="cboLocation" class="width150" id="cboLocation" multiple="multiple">


$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#cboLocation").dropdownchecklist( {
        emptyText:'Select Something', // couldn't see the thing
        firstItemChecksAll: true,
        onComplete: function () { getValue() } //, alert('hello') }
    });

    function getValue() {
        if($('.ui-dropdownchecklist-item input:checked').length > 0) {
        alert('hai');
        }
    }       
});
```